# How to configure Intellij idea code formatting to according my example

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, rest-assured, jgiven

I have butiful code in my tests

```
public void createEntity(String jsonString) {   
    response = getBaseRequestWithCurrentCookie()
            .given().
                    body(jsonString).
                    contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .when().
                    post()
            .then().
                    log().ifError().
                    extract().response();
}
```

But how to configure intellij Idea code style(for Java) so that it doesn't align it ?

```
public void createEntity(String jsonString) {
    response = getBaseRequestWithCurrentCookie()
            .given().
            body(jsonString).
            contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .when().
            post()
            .then().
            log().ifError().
            extract().response();
}
```

Comment: Do you want 1st or 2nd formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add builder method names to Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Chained method calls | **Builder methods**
2. Enable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Chained method calls | **Keep builder methods indents** option:

[image]